# R-value of textiles

Tags: insulation, energy-efficiency

Does anyone know of any good sources of information about the R-value of various textiles, like blankets and quilts of various materials/thicknesses in various conditions?

Comment: I suspect there are too many variables to assign an R-value for various textiles, (I.e.: material, weave, thickness, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. I was hoping maybe there was some study from the military or something where they compared standardized sleeping bags or something like that. But I haven't found anything.

Comment: If you have access to a university or engineering library, ASHRAE 90.1 Fundamentals Handbook may have this information.